# Ubuntu 17.10 kernel panic not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, kernel

I am getting a kernel panic "not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)" with kernel 4.13.0-43 on Ubuntu 17.10. I can boot just fine with 4.13.0-41. After a successful boot using 4.13.0-41 I can get 4.13.0-43 to boot if I boot in text mode and remove the quiet and splash options. Anyone have any ideas as to what is happening? My disk drive is a 250Gb disk with one partition (I accepted the default options when I installed the system).

Comment: Start the **Disks** application and take a look at the **SMART Data & Tests**.

Comment: I checked the SMART status of the disk and it passed. I just ran the latest updates and a new version of util-linux was installed. I have rebooted the laptop 5 or 6 times now using the 4.13.0-43 version of the kernel. The problem started last week after the unattended upgrades ran. I am going to keep my eye on this for a while. Perhaps the patch to util-linux solved the issue.

Comment: please see my answer for more procedure...

Comment: I ran the file system checker as suggested and no errors were found. My system is getting the same error again after about 10 successful reboots.

Comment: please see the update to my answer...

Comment: I ran memtest+ through a complete test cycle. No errors were reported.

Comment: Since your problem sounds like it's intermittent, you may have to run multiple passes of memtest. Did you rebuild initramfs? You might search askubuntu for "VFS" and see what others have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the SMART status, lets check your file system...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

**Rebuild initramfs...**

In `terminal`...

- `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.13.0-43-generic` # update initramfs
- `reboot` # to version 4.13.0.43

**Run memtest...**

- Go to **http://www.memtest.org** or **https://www.memtest86.com/** and download/run memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the tests to confirm good memory.

Comment: I ran the update-initramfs command. No errors were reported and I have successfully booted the laptop 15 times in a row with the 4.13.0-43-generic kernel. It seems to be behaving now. Thank you.