# Kernel 4.15.0-118 causing kernel panic on Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, kernel

It looks like the 4.15.0-118 is causing a kernel panic during boot on my machine (Alienware 15 R3 from Dell).

Booting with the previous kernel works.

Last line in the output I get when attempting to boot with the new kernel is:
`---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

Maybe it has something to do with my partition encryption with LUKS (I have a Windows partition, and a LUKS partition)?

I tried following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and went to Launchpad, but couldn't figure out how to file a bug there...

Does anybody else have the problem?
I tried solving it temporarily by [changing the GRUB to boot the older kernel by default](https://kowalczyk.me/change-default-kernel-in-ubuntu-18-04/) (without me going through advance boot options when I turn on the machine). But it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Yup, that's why I added an answer with the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix in [Ubuntu 17.10 kernel panic not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041034/ubuntu-17-10-kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-b)

Had to run only `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-118-generic`